# Missing Metrics - Azure Spring Cloud

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-spring-cloud

I have a *Azure Spring Cloud* resource in Azure that contains two apps. To keep it simple lets call these apps *App A* and *App B*.

I wanted to set up monitoring and alerting for these two apps but only one of them actually writes the required metrics. According to the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/concept-metrics) the app dashboard should display certain metrics like *tomcat.global.request.total.count* but only *App A* does that. *App B* doesn't write those metrics and I'm wondering why because I can't find any indication in the Azure documentation that I have to setup something for this to work.

> **App A Metrics Overview** [image: App A Metrics Overview]
>
> **App B Metrics Overview** [image: App B Metrics Overview]
>
> *(Both apps had traffic in the displayed timeframe)*

Do I have to install some maven packages or do some other configuration to get these default metrics to work? I tried to install the maven package *applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter* but that didn't change anything.

Comment: As per this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/how-to-prepare-app-deployment?pivots=programming-language-java#metrics), have  you specified  `spring.jmx.enabled=true` in your configuration property. Otherwise, metrics can't be visualized in Azure portal.

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT I checked both applications and neither of them has the config parameter `spring.jmx.enabled=true` set. But _App A_ has the `spring-boot-starter-actuator`  maven package installed and _App B_ doesn't. I will try to install that package and check if that changes something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven package `spring-boot-starter-actuator` was missing as per this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/how-to-prepare-app-deployment?pivots=programming-language-java#metrics). After I added the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` to my project the metrics started working in Azure. It was not necessary to set the configuration `spring.jmx.enabled=true`